# Importing from PySide or PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, pyside, python-import

I'd like to use either PyQt4 or PySide for imports, whichever is installed. For some reason though I can't do this:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from QtGui import QApplication
```

Instead of the last line, I have to do this, I'm not sure why:

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication
```

That doesn't bother me too much, but it makes it very frustrating importing multiple things using whichever library is installed:

```
try:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore
    from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame, QAction, ...
    ...
except ImportError:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore
    from PySide.QtGui import QApplication, QMainWindow, QFrame, QAction, ...
    ...
```

It gets pretty repetitive.

Also, this doesn't work, Python won't allow it:

```
import PyQt4 as SomeQt
from SomeQt import QtGui
```

So I can't find a good way to cut down on repetition between the PyQt4 and PySide sections. Is there a better way? Is there any harm in just using import *:

```
try:
    from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    ...
except ImportError:
    from PySide import QtGui, QtWebKit, QtCore
    from PySide.QtGui *
    ...
```

to at least cut down on the amount of repetition necessary?

Comment: Nope no harm in it usually, however once in a while doing `import *` will cause a name conflict and so a class/function might not be what you are expecting it to be.

Answer (score 1):

I would just do following:

```
try:
    from PyQt4.QtCore import *
    from PyQt4.QtGui import *
    ...
except ImportError:
    from PySide.QtCore import *
    from PySide.QtGui import *
    ...

...
QThread()
QApplication()
QWidget()
...
```

Wild imports are usually discouraged by Python community and best practice. The reasoning is that you are unnecessarily polluting your namespace. Me personally, I do not care for `Qt`, as every class name is starting with `Q`, e.g. `QSomething`. This makes it in my opinion very unlikely to collide with another class names from my or 3rd party modules.

To be safe, you can also do something like:

```
try:
    from PyQt4 import QtCore as Qc
    from PyQt4 import QtGui as Qg
    ...
except ImportError:
    from PySide import QtCore as Qc
    from PySide import QtGui as Qg
    ...

...
Qc.QThread()
Qc.QApplication()
Qg.QWidget()
...
```